# Amazon S3 Copy files after date and with regex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, command-line-interface

I'm trying to copy some files from S3 sourceBucket to targetBucket, but I need to filter by date and by prefix.
I wish it could be done with AWS CLI, but at the moment I'm stuck with [list-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) or with cp command.

I can filter correctly with

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket sourceBucket --query 'Contents[?(LastModified > `2021-09-01`)]' --prefix "somePrefix_"
```

With the CP I can copy the files, but only by prefix

```
aws s3 cp s3://sourceBucket/ s3://targetBucket/ --recursive --include "somePrefix" --exclude "*"
```

I tried to come up with some ideas using the header `--x-amz-copy-source-if-modified-since` but it looks like you can use it with the command `aws s3api copy-object` and it copies one item at a time ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html)).
I read some answers/docs and I think I understood che cp command doesn't filter by date, but only by prefix.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you already have a list with objects you want to copy to another bucket, I suggest writing a bash script which does the copying for multiple objects:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_BUCKET="<my-bucket>"
DESTINATION_BUCKET="<my-other-bucket>"
PREFIX="<some-prefix>"

content=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $SOURCE_BUCKET --query 'Contents[?(LastModified > `2021-09-01`)]' --prefix $PREFIX | jq -r ".[].Key")

for file in $content;
do
    aws s3api copy-object --copy-source $SOURCE_BUCKET/$file --key $file --bucket $DESTINATION_BUCKET | jq
done
```

Please note, this scripts requires `jq` to be installed.

Comment: You can probably avoid `jq` by using `'Contents[?(LastModified > "2021-09-01")].Key'`

Comment: Thank you @Ervin , the script works just fine! I hoped I could do it in one command line, but this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Working fine. Additionally, In the logging observed Broken pipe exception so enclosed the copy-object command in "$(aws copy-object * *)" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621794/exception-ignored-in-io-textiowrapper-name-stdout-mode-w-encoding-utf